# How to reset gedit preferences?

Tags: gedit

gedit lately suddenly started to open new files in new windows and it is really frustrating to me. I searched graphical preferences, preferences listed by [How to change gedit preferences from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571877/how-to-change-gedit-preferences-from-terminal) and I also tried to uninstall gedit, remove all gedit files/folders in $HOME and reinstall gedit back, but nothing of that didn't help.

Comment: Uninstall needs to be a "purge" to remove personal settings ;)

Comment: I uninstall everything using purge, but in case of gedit it just didn't work. Maybe a bug?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you use? Is it clean install or upgrade?

Comment: Clean 18.04 Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gedit settings are saved in GSettings or DConf, so you can reset them with the following command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gedit/
```

Comment: Thank you, so my issue is a bug, this preferences reset also didn't help with initial problem...