# Ubuntu 20.04: Gedit preferences manager does not allow interactions

Tags: gnome, configuration, gedit, dconf

I am trying to install plugins on Gedit v3.36.2 under a clean Ubuntu 20.04 installation.
I'm opening the preferences but I checking/unchecking the various options doesn't work: Gedit doesn't listen!

The weird thing is that I can check/uncheck only a certain amount of options (i.e. "Display grid pattern", "Enable text wrapping") but when I change those and quit 'Gedit" then the settings aren't saved.

I also tried changing the preferences using `dconf-editor` but again, I cannot change specific values.

I tried to reset the configuration by running `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gedit/` but I get `error: The given address is empty`.

Note that Gedit is running on a remote host and I'm ssh-ing to it. Also I don't have sudo rights so the solution found in [Can not click checkboxes in preferences in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266451/can-not-click-checkboxes-in-preferences-in-gedit) cannot be applied.

Any idean on how to solve that?